# Converting a character into a space in C arrays

Tags: c, arrays, encryption, character

So lets say I have received a message that resembles the following

> "L2N5*8R10!11T0A1K3Y14#4W7O6O9C12R13"

and I am expected to sort out the characters in accordance to the numbers succeeding them and change the characters that are not letters into a space. I have no problem doing the sorting out part, I am only having a trouble while trying to write a function that will change those characters into space. 
The out put should be something like this

> TALK NOW OR CRY

but I am getting

> TALK#NOW*OR!CRY

Can anyone help me figure out what my function should look like so that I can be able to change the characters into space??

Comment: What are you trying now?

Comment: even that your function hasn't worked properly, you still need to show it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a problem with your code, then you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Help us help you without wasting time on guessing.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you guys, I have just assumed that posting the code won't be much use, However I have figured it out.  Here is the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you show your code, we'll only be able to guess!!

However, as a general suggestion, I would recommended, you should check each entry against [`isalpha()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha). In case you got a return value of 0, replace the entry with a .

Comment: That is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Olaf With all due respect, I think currently OP needs to differenciate between alpha/non-alpha characters and the function/approach I mentioned will do the job. How exactly this is not an answer?

Comment: It cannot be, because - as you also wrote - the question lacks required information. It is not even sure what OP really means with "characters". However, if he provides the necessary information and you prove right, drop me a comment and I'll revisit.